# format timespan which is extracted from reflections to display only hours and minutes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tostring, timespan, typeconverter

I am having a function to which I will pass an anonymous object and in turn I have to return a timespan value that will display the value in hh:mm format.have a look below for my code snippet.

```
public string GetTime(Object obj, string propName)
{
   TimeSpan? time = obj.Gettype().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);

   return time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
}
```

I am getting correct value in to time variable and when I try to convert in to string it says no ToString function takes 1 arguments

I even tried to convert by using TimeSpan.parse then it allowed me to convert here but, it is giving me wrong values as output

here is my TimeSpan parse:

```
return TimeSpan.Parse(time.ToString()).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

some how I want to get hh:mm as string that to perfectly exact values.
so please any work around.........

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public string GetTime(Object obj, string propName)
{
   TimeSpan? time = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);

   // The difference is here... If time has a value, then take it
   // and format it, otherwise return an empty string.
   return time.HasValue ? time.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm") : string.Empty;
}
```

While the `TimeSpan.ToString()` has the overload you want, the `TimeSpan?` doesn't.